# Create new pandas df from matching numpy array with pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following 3x3x3 (3 rows, 3 columns with 3 elements in each cell) numpy array...

```
[[[1, 1, 19],
  [2, 2, 29],
  [3, 3, 39]],
 [[4, 4, 49],
  [1, 1, 19],
  [2, 2, 29]],
 [[3, 3, 39],
  [9, 9, 99],
  [8, 8, 89]]]
```

and the following pandas dataframe...

```
col0 col1 col2 col3
1    1    19    10
2    2    29    20
3    3    39    30
4    4    49    40
8    8    89    80
9    9    99    90
```

I want to generate a new pandas data frame using values from col3, that matches each 3 element array (e.g. [1, 1, 19] or [4, 4. 49]) with col0, col1, col3.

Order of the 3 element array is important, the first element must match to col0, and second to col1 and so on.

The resulting data frame would look like the following...

```
colA colB colC
10   20   30
40   10   20
30   90   80
```

Comment: Your desired output contains the number `80` which appears nowhere in the input.  Can you clarify how the input maps to the output?

Comment: I was trying to imply that original data frame followed a pattern, but I have changed it to be explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the array `needles` and the DataFrame `haystack`.  First, index the haystack:

```
haystack.set_index(['col0', 'col1', 'col2'], inplace=True)
```

Now you can get the values for the first set of needles:

```
haystack.loc[list(map(tuple, needles[0]))]
```

This gives you the first row of your solution (in `col3`):

```
                col3
col0 col1 col2      
1    1    19      10
2    2    29      20
3    3    39      30
```

Finally, do that for every 3x3 array along the first axis of `needles`:

```
pd.DataFrame(haystack.loc[list(map(tuple, pin))].col3.values for pin in needles)
```

This gives you the result:

```
    0   1   2
0  10  20  30
1  40  10  20
2  30  90  80
```

An alternative which may or may not be faster:

```
pd.DataFrame(haystack.col3[pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(pin.T)].values for pin in needles)
```

The `map` or `MultiIndex.from_arrays()` is needed because unfortunately Pandas doesn't allow MultiIndex lookups by 2D arrays--only by lists (or arrays) of tuples.  For more on that, see: [Pandas MultiIndex lookup with Numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493094/pandas-multiindex-lookup-with-numpy-arrays)